# Harmonic series and converging sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence such that $a_n\to1$, define $$ 
> \sum_{n\geq1}\frac{a_n}{n} $$ Does the above series diverge as the
> harmonic series does?

My toolbox about series is a little restricted so my attempt will be a little lacking. The ratio test clearly doesn't work because the limit will go to one. We can't really apply  the integral test, because we lack knowledge about $a_n$. I appreciate any tips or help. However we can see that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n/n=0$ so we can't really rule out convergence.

Comment: Can you say that eventually, i.e., for $n > N$ for some integer $N$, that $a_n > 1/2$ so that $$\sum_{n \geq N} \frac{a_n}{n} > \sum_{n \geq N} \frac{1/2}{n}  \text{?}$$

Comment: For $n$ sufficiently large, $a_n>.9$, so use comparison to $\sum(.9/n)$.

Comment: Ah, those are great tips, I think I know the way now, thanks!

Comment: We take $\epsilon$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0, |a_n-1|<\epsilon$ thus $a_n>1-\epsilon$ for large enough $n$ and split the series at $n_0$ such that the series of elements with $n\geq n_0$ can be minored by the harmonic series times a constant, right?

Comment: Yes. Write it up, and post it as an answer. Later on, you can "accept" it.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the reminder =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 1$ thus
$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \quad \exists n_0 \in\mathbb{N} \quad \text{s.t.} \quad |a_n-1|<\epsilon
$$
and we may choose $\epsilon=0.5 \;$ such that we obtain the following inequality for $n\geq n_0(\epsilon)$,
$$
\frac{1}{2} = 1-\frac{1}{2}< a_n < 1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}
$$
This way we can decompose the series as below,

\begin{align}
\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{a_n}{n} &= \sum_{1\leq n < n_0}\frac{a_n}{n} + \sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{a_n}{n}   \\
&\geq \sum_{1\leq n < n_0}\frac{a_n}{n} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{1}{n} 
\end{align}
which shows us that the series is minored by the harmonic series times a constant plus a finite series and let us conclude by the comparison test that the initial series diverges.

Comment: Not $-1/2<a_n<1/2$, but $1/2<a_n<3/2$.